# Approximation of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus, approximation, approximation-theory

Let $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ and $q:\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be analytic (well-behaved) functions. Let $n>m$, and $\int_{\mathbb{R}^{n-m}}fd\lambda = q$. Then, if I am trying to find an estimator (such as a neural network, or something else) of either one by using gradient descent on the error, I'd think finding an estimator of $q$ is "easier" than $f$. Where "easier" means I can get less error, or the error function decreases faster, or my estimator requires less parameters, or maybe another notion of "easier" natural to humans.

Is there some theoretical result or theory to support my thought process? Or is it that we can't really know? Or do I need to make my definition of "easier" more precise?

In simple words: $f(x,y)$, $q(y)$, and $\int fdx=q$. So, I want to know which one between $f$ and $q$ I can approximate more "easily".

Comment: Isn't it almost always the one of smaller dimension? Unless you know some special properties of $f$ i would say $q$ is easier to estimate.

Comment: yes, that's what I think. But I'd like to know if there's some rigorous proof or result showing that.

Comment: Wikipedia has a decent page on this so called "Curse of Dimensionality", see here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality

Comment: The gist of it is that volume increases exponentially in higher dimension, so naturally errors increase exponentially as well.

Comment: I am familiar with Curse of Dimensionality, but I'd like something more rigorous. Also, reading the definition from Wikipedia: "The common theme of these problems is that when the dimensionality increases, the volume of the space increases so fast that the available data become sparse." That's not exactly my issue here. I guess I can try to find a more rigorous result pertinent to my problem along that line. Thanks!